# Why isn't the vue/this-in-template ESLint rule automatically fixable?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In Vue.JS, templates don't need to use `this` to access component variables. The Vue extension for ESLint includes the rule [vue/this-in-template](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/this-in-template.html) to warn when `this` is unnecessarily used, such as in the below example.

```html
<template>
  <img 
    v-if="this.type == 'image'" 
    :src="this.imageURL" 
    class="cardImage" 
  />
</template>
```

```sh
Line 2: error  Unexpected usage of 'this'  vue/this-in-template
Line 3: error  Unexpected usage of 'this'  vue/this-in-template
```

However, this rule is one of only a few others that aren't automatically fixable. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation of `vue/this-in-template`](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/467ef96/lib/rules/this-in-template.js#L91) currently does not implement [`fix()`](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#applying-fixes), which is required to auto-fix the error.

I think it's not implemented yet possibly because there might be some tricky examples (maybe dynamic property names) that require a non-trivial fix up. I also don't see any safety issues in removing `this` from the template.